# ForeSquareApi :Getting list of venues in near by location

Tags: foursquare

I'm using Foursquare API to get a list of venues by using v2/venues/search API endpoint but here i am getting all categories of list but i need only Restaurants list

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a `categoryId` parameter to filter by a Foursquare categoryId. To get an up-to-date list of categories, see the [venues/categories](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories) endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

try this

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?radius=1000&ll=40.723229,-74.006570&limit=50&client_id=YOUR CLIENT_ID&v=20130412&client_secret=YOUE CLIENT_SECRET&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4d4b7105d754a06376d81259